# Error in simple wxpython execution example

Tags: execute, wxpython

As a totally wxpython newbie, I’ve unsuccessfully tried to execute this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False) 
    pid = wx.Execute('echo blabla', wx.EXEC_ASYNC)
    print(pid)
```

It returns pid = 0, i.e.,  the [command could not be executed](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.functions.html?highlight=execute#wx.Execute). I am using Python 3.7.5 with wxPython 4.1.0 on Windows 10. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Running your example result in an error for me:

> Execution of command 'echo blabla' failed (error 2: the system cannot
> find the file specified.)

Adding `cmd /c` to the start of the command string results in the following output:

```
11412
blabla
```

The full code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False) 
    pid = wx.Execute('cmd /c echo blabla', wx.EXEC_ASYNC)
    print(pid)
```

Comment: I think this message solves the problem: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/using-wx-execute/34778/4?u=franpena